# How to make maths formulas align with text in LATEX?

Tags: anki

I want to make the LATEX smaller (same size as normal text) and the fraction align with the text. I didn't find how.

```
La fonction [$]\frac{1}{x}[/$] est dérivable sur [$]\mathbb{R^{*} }[/$] et sa dérivée est [$]-\frac{1}{x^2}[/$].
```

[image: 1]

I just tried this but I don't like the fact that everything is latex...

```
[$]\text{La fonction }\frac{1}{x}\text{ est dérivable sur }\mathbb{R^{*} }\text{ et sa dérivée est }-\frac{1}{x^2}\text{.}[/$]
```

[image: 2]

Comment: The first code is not LaTeX code!

Comment: sorry, I'm on Anki that's why my code is like that. The code is actually working, I just need to find how to align latex and normal text.

Comment: I have no idea, as I don't know Anki. It seems to align math formulæ on the base line.  Maybe try something like `\vcenter{\hbox{$formula $}}` if this command is accessible to you, but I'm sure there are simpler solutions.